# how to make a loop and if statement that loops through a different groups of radio buttons (javascript)

Tags: html, loops, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

```
**HTML**
<li class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="Answer1" value="A">A</input><br>

            <input type="radio" name="Answer1" value="B">B</input><br>

            <input type="radio" name="Answer1" value="C">C</input><br>

            <input type="radio" name="Answer1" value="D">D</input><br>
        </li>

<li class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="Answer2" value="A">A</input><br>

            <input type="radio" name="Answer2" value="B">B</input><br>

            <input type="radio" name="Answer2" value="C">C</input><br>

            <input type="radio" name="Answer2" value="D">D</input><br>
        </li>

<li class="option">
            <input type="radio" name="Answer3" value="A">A</input><br>

            <input type="radio" name="Answer3" value="B">B</input><br>

            <input type="radio" name="Answer3" value="C">C</input><br>

            <input type="radio" name="Answer3" value="D">D</input><br>
```

I am creating an online survey. At the end of the survey there is a submit button which will get an alert of either "Please answer all questions" or "Submitted". Which alert is used is dependant on whether the user has answered all the questions or not. Im not sure how to create this loop. Please help.

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: sure, but i prefer javascript

Comment: Well here's a jquery option: `if($(':radio:checked').length == $('li.option').length){alert('submitted')}else{...}`

Comment: Your HTML is a bit invalid--`<input type="radio/>` is a self closing tag.

Comment: And how would i implement jquery into bootstrap, its a bit of a stupid question but im quite new to this

Comment: Ermmmm...if your using Bootstrap, jQuery is already included. Bootstraps JS requires jQuery to run. Let me put a demo together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, [**take a look at this demo boootply**](http://www.bootply.com/8GBDYb76rf). Since you're using Bootstrap, jQuery should already be part of your page. Here's the relevent code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submitBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('li.option :radio:checked').length == $('li.option').length){
        // enter code here to submit your form
        alert('submitted');
    }else{
        alert('Please answer all questions');
    }
  });
});
```

And the HTML corrected to:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="option">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="Answer1" value="A">A
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="Answer1" value="B">B
        </label>
```

etc..

And just in case, here's the link markup for the bootstrap/jQuery files:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified jQuery-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $('li.option :radio:checked').length == $('li.option').length) I like this. Instead of hard coding how many items there are dynamically getting the array count for how many questions there are!

Comment: Thank you so much, i have been trying to figure this out for 3 days, and i finally have the answer!!! THANKYOU